# How to efficiently do a limit query on MongoDB GridFS

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, mongo-java-driver

I cannot seem to find an efficient way to do a query against MongoDB GridFS that contains a limit of n files.

Here is what I have tried.

```
DBCursor fileList = products.getFileList().limit(10);
while(fileList.hasNext()){
    DBObject fileDef = fileList.next();
    file = products.findOne((String)fileDef.get("filename"));
    InputStream stream = file.getInputStream();
    ...
}
```

The problem with that is that there are actually 21 query operations that occur.

First is the getFileList() which actually calls DBCollection.find().

Then for each result a findOne() occurs which ends up calling DBCollection.find({"filename":filename}) `10` times.

After that, when I call read on the input stream, it calls findOne("files_id":id) on the chunks collection for all `10` files.

---

I noticed that in GridFS.find() it queries the files collection, converts each DBObject to a GridFSDBFile, and sets its (fs) variable to `this`(GridFS). (all this via injectGridFSInstance(Object))

If the getFileList() operation did this as well then all would be well, but it just returns a standard cursor. You can cast the DBObject to a GridFSDBFile but when you try to call read on the InputStream it complains that there is no GridFS instance defined and therefore does not have the information it needs to go and get the chunks.

I would love to be able to set the fs variable but it is private.

---

Bottom line:

Is there a way to do a query on GridFS that includes a .limit(n) that does not have to double the number of query operations.